# Display the newest result from my database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a webpage that displays the newest result from a database as a news article. 
The parts of the database are title, bodytext and created although I wish to keep created hidden. I am quite new to PHP and don't have any idea how to do this, could i please get some help just to display it as:

title
bodytext

I need to be able to connect to the database with my details then display the results in a div I have set up, although I only want to show the newest result!

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on some tutorials, or buy a descent book.

As for getting the latest result, you can sort on the `created` column, and only get the first element using `LIMIT`.

Comment: I have been reading up on it but I work at a web developing place and I dont do server side scripting so everything I know is design related.

Answer (score 0):

My example uses the PDO class for the database handle

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT title, bodytext FROM newstable ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1');
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then to get the result out in your div you use:

```
$title = $result['title'];
$story = $result['bodytext'];
```

Answer (score 0):

a very good way :

1 - create a column in that table named "ts" of type "int"
2 - when inserting values of new article to the table , "insert into .... ts='".date("U")."' ..."
3 - select * from [table name] ... order by ts desc limit 1

by this way you can even get the time this article has been saved `$saved=date("d-m-Y h:i A",$result->ts);` ... or even know the age in seconds for this `article $age=date("U")-$result->ts;` ...